# How do I control 1 object with 2 bones?

Tags: modeling, armature, bones

I have this 3d model and as you can see 2 bones are connected to that part with screws on it. and I want it to be controlled with both arms not just one arm. So basically how do I "stick" the upper arm to that object as well so it doesn't come off?
I use 2 IK here.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add `Bone Constraint` `Copy Transforms` or `Copy Rotation` if you only need that
[Video Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hiDH02qWaPE)

[image]

Comment: copy transform doesn't really do anything for me :(

Comment: try copy rotation?

Comment: well, kind of but not perfect, thanks! I could tweak it myself I guess in animation, don't have much time the project is due tomorrow haha

Answer (score 0):

Similar to kemplerart's answer, try using a `Track To` or `Damped Track` constraint on your arm bone(s). Target the next bone or  the object.

If you want to offset it from the bone itself, try parenting an empty to the bone for the top section While it's placed over one of the screws (for example) then target your constraint to the empty.

You may have to play around with the rotation/track axes and the rotation space (eg. World Space / Local Space etc.) to get the desired result.